Android date parse difference from unit test
I have an issue where the date parsed in unit test is different from running on real device.
This is the time I need to parse and find the difference.
val startStr = "2024-06-16T15:35:08.363341+0000"
val endStr = "2024-06-16T15:50:08.340638+0000"

The code I run is

fun diff() :String {
    val startStr = "2024-06-16T15:35:08.363341+0000"
    val endStr = "2024-06-16T15:50:08.340638+0000"
    val differenceInTimeFormat = getDifferenceInTimeFormat(date(startStr), date(endStr))
    return differenceInTimeFormat
}

private fun date(startStr: String): Date = try {
    val dateFormat3 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ", Locale.US)
    dateFormat3.parse(startStr)!!
} catch (e: ParseException) {
    throw Exception()
}

private fun getDifferenceInTimeFormat(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): String {
    val diffInMilli = endDate.time - startDate.time
    val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffInMilli)
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMilli) % 60
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMilli) % 60
    return String.format(Settings.localeDefault, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
}


On device it returns
00:14:59
and on unit test returns

Expected :00:14:37 Actual   :00:14:59

@Test
fun addition_isCorrect() {
    assertEquals(diff(), "00:14:49")
}

Same issue is with using this as formatting
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
How to solve the issue of time difference parsing between unit test and real device?

You should consider not using the legacy Date and SimpleDateFormat classes there are better way to handle date in Android see here
Try using the ZonedDateTime class:
private fun date(startStr: String): ZonedDateTime = try {
    ZonedDateTime.parse(startStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ", Locale.ENGLISH))
} catch (e: ParseException) {
    throw Exception()
}

private fun getDifferenceInTimeFormat(startDate: ZonedDateTime, endDate: ZonedDateTime): String {
    val duration = Duration.between(startDate, endDate)
    return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart())
}

